# mod_rewrite + django causing incorrect redirect URLs post login

Tags: django, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a Django project with an app named "Surveys" - it is desired that URLs such as http://example.com/Surveys/ViewInspection/1 are accessible via http://example.com/Inspections/ViewInspection/1.

Using Apache 2.4 and mod_rewrite, I have the following set of rules in place to allow this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/Inspections(.+)$ /Surveys$1 [PT]
```

and all appears to work fine, except where a non-authenticated user attempts to access the above URL (the view for which has the @login_required decorator.

At this point, the user is bounced to the login screen with parameters:

```
/Auth/Login?next=/Ins/Surveys/ViewInspection/1
```

After a bit of digging, "/Ins/Surveys/ViewInspection/1" is the value for request.path, whereas request.path_info is correctly set as /Surveys/ViewInspection/1 - the Auth code is taking .path and getting it wrong. If I use a shorter string than "Inspections" the Ins part decreases until disappearing, when it all works fine.

mod_rewrite logs look correct in this instance:

```
[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.617840 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a53910a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /Inspections/ViewInspection/2

[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.617906 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a53910a0/initial] applying pattern '^/Inspections(.+)$' to uri '/Inspections/ViewInspection/2'

[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.617940 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a53910a0/initial] rewrite '/Inspections/ViewInspection/2' -> '/Surveys/ViewInspection/2'

[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.617956 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a53910a0/initial] forcing '/Surveys/ViewInspection/2' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler

[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.618103 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a54060a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /Surveys/ViewInspection/2

[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.618119 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a54060a0/subreq] applying pattern '^/Inspections(.+)$' to uri '/Surveys/ViewInspection/2'

[Tue Feb 23 23:52:49.618131 2021] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2760:tid 140156097316608] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 213.18.147.204:4054] 213.18.147.204 - - [hostname/sid#7f78a4651338][rid#7f78a54060a0/subreq] pass through /Surveys/ViewInspection/2
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here to cause request.path to be wrong and foul up the redirects after login?

If I shorten the "Inspections" part in the re-write rule, it correspondingly shortens the "Ins" part of the incorrect request.path - so a short (<8 character) string in place causes everything to work perfectly. I just can't see where this is taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding WSGI middleware to drop out the WSGI info to the Apache error log, I've tracked down the culprit to line 177 in django.core.handlers.wsgi.py

```
if script_url:
       if b'//' in script_url:
           # mod_wsgi squashes multiple successive slashes in PATH_INFO,
           # do the same with script_url before manipulating paths (#17133).
           script_url = _slashes_re.sub(b'/', script_url)
       path_info = get_bytes_from_wsgi(environ, 'PATH_INFO', '')
       script_name = script_url[:-len(path_info)] if path_info else script_url
   else:
       script_name = get_bytes_from_wsgi(environ, 'SCRIPT_NAME', '')
```

Here, we land up in this little block of code because script_name is a zero string from mod_wsgi (I'm not in a sub directory).  `path_info` is being set by Apache to `/Surveys/ViewInspection/1` (correct, from mod_rewrite); `script_url` is `/Inspections/ViewInspection/1` (again correct - the pre- mod_rewrite URL).

The code `script_url[:-len(path_info)]` blindly strips away the length on path_info as the script name, and gets it wrong.

The workround here is to add:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ""
```

to the Django settings.py file.